# Why is Lua's string.gsub not taking a replace pattern from a variable?

Tags: lua

In the following Lua code, I attempt to implement a selector syntax that changes its value based on the *Minecraft* "world" a "wood" is found in. But the `gsub` function seems to be never taking in the selector value, always acting as if `%1` is given.

```
local woodTypeWorld = {
  Oak = 'overworld',
  Crimson = 'nether',
}
local item = '${Log,Stem}'
-- Force an order of iteration
for _, wood in ipairs({'Oak', 'Crimson'}) do
  -- Parse ${,} (world-select) syntax
  local selector = (woodTypeWorld[wood] == 'overworld') and "%1" or "%2"
  print(woodTypeWorld[wood] .. " -> " .. selector)
  item = item:gsub("%${(.-),(.-)}", selector)
  print(wood .. ' ' .. item)
end
```

In other words, my expected output is:

```
overworld -> %1
Oak Log
nether -> %2
Crimson Stem
```

While the actual thing I get is:

```
overworld -> %1
Oak Log
nether -> %2
Crimson Log
```

This occurs on the Gamepedia instance of MediaWiki Lua, an repl.it instance of Lua, and the official [demo page](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) for the Lua language. I have tried doing the following to no avail:

- Rewriting the selector as a function `function (_, o, n) (woodTypeWorld[wood] == 'overworld') and o or n end`
- Expanding the fake ternary and/or statements into `if`
- Adding ",1" to the gsub list.
- Assembling the selector from a `%` and a number determined by a ternary expression
- Explicitly calling `string.gsub` or MediaWiki's special UTF-8 aware `mw.ustring.gsub`

In addition:

- The gsub does work as documented when `selector` is replaced with a string literal.
- If the ipairs order is reversed, the output changes to all "Stem" instead. It is as if the selector is cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first iteration of the loop changes `item`, and then it stays changed for the rest of the iterations, since it no longer matches the pattern. To fix it, instead of overwriting it, save the `gsub` result to another variable, like this:

```
local woodTypeWorld = {
  Oak = 'overworld',
  Crimson = 'nether',
}
local item = '${Log,Stem}'
-- Force an order of iteration
for _, wood in ipairs({'Oak', 'Crimson'}) do
  -- Parse ${,} (world-select) syntax
  local selector = (woodTypeWorld[wood] == 'overworld') and "%1" or "%2"
  print(woodTypeWorld[wood] .. " -> " .. selector)
  local item2 = item:gsub("%${(.-),(.-)}", selector)
  print(wood .. ' ' .. item2)
end
```